# Use a modifier with find command's regex?

Tags: find, regular-expression, newlines

I'm trying to use the find command's regex to match newlines using the dot character.  This usually is accomplished via the `s` modifier; however, different regex engines have different formats and I can't figure out exactly how to write the regex so that the find command will match newlines.  For example, how would I change the following simple command to match all files including those containing newlines in their names:

```
find /home/user -regex ".*"
```

I've tried `"(?s).*"`, `"/.*/s"`, and probably a few others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version of GNU find supports a few different regex variants, which can be chosen with `-regextype`:

> valid types are ‘findutils-default’, ‘awk’, ‘egrep’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’, ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’, ‘posix-extended’, ‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’.

Almost all of those let the dot match a newline, ...except `emacs`, which is the default.

So, use some other one. `posix-extended` is probably sane enough:

```
$ touch hello $'new\nline'
$ find . -type f -regex '.*'
./hello
$ find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*'
./hello
./new?line
```

If you're running some other `find`, your mileage may vary. On a quick test, the one on my Mac does match newlines with `.` by default.

Then again, for simple patterns, you could just use `-name` which takes shell globs (and shouldn't have issues with newlines).

The `(?s)` looks like a feature of PCRE/Perl regexes, and I don't see `find` supporting that. As for `/.*/s`, `find` takes just the raw pattern, no separators, and hence no trailing options.

Comment: What's the point of `-regex '.*'` Can't you just not use `-regex` instead?

Comment: @Kusalananda, they appear to be asking exactly about how to get the dot in a regex to match newlines too. Of course `-regex '.*'`  is a bit silly in itself, any other regex would do.

Answer (score -2):

The command

```bsh
find ~user
```

would find all names, including those containing newlines. Add `-type f` if you want to only find regular files.

If you don't want to restrict the matching of names, don't use a test on the names.

To restrict the names matched using substrings, you could use a globbing pattern with the `-name` test.  Both `*` and `?` matches newlines in a globbing pattern, both in the shell in general and in the `-name` test of `find`:

Example using standard `find`:

```
$ find . -name 'file?name'
./file
name
```

```
$ find . -name 'file*name'
./file
name
```

```
$ find . -name 'd*name'
./dir
name
```

```
$ echo ./d*name
./dir
name
```

---

Answer to misunderstood question ("How may I find names containing newlines"):

Using standard `find`:

```bsh
find ~user -name '*
*'
```

Using "C-strings" in shells that support these (still using standard `find`)

```bsh
find ~user -name $'*\n*'
```

None of the built-in regular expression types normally available in GNU `find` is able to match a newline with `\n`, so you're left using a literal newline, just like in the globbing patterns above.  This means it's probably easier to use  a standard `-name` test than a non-portable `-regex` test.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question: it's to match names that _may_ contain a newline, not match that _must_ contain a newline. With GNU find, `find -regex '.*'` does not match file names containing newlines.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks. Updated.

Comment: The updated answer works for the specific toy example in the question, but isn't generalizable to any other case.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' It's difficult to see what cases they need covered and what doesn't work. It's a literal solution to their actual question.

Comment: @Kusalananda, they're asking "how to write the regex so that [it] will match newlines", and mentioning `(?s)` and `.../s`, both of which are ways in Perl for enabling the `s` option to the regex. By default, the `.` in Perl doesn't match newlines, but with the `s` option it does. Try e.g. `perl -e 'print "yes\n" if "foo\nbar" =~ /foo.bar/'` vs. `=~ /foo.bar/s` or `=~ /(?s)foo.bar/'`

Comment: @ilkkachu Hmm... Why don't they use a globbing pattern then? Both `*` and `?` matches newlines. It's furthermore portable and you don't have to bother about regular expressions or whatever type of them you have available.